# how to delete the short lists from a long nested list even the items are not continuous using Python?

Tags: python, list, long-integer, short

For example:

```
t=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 5], [4, 5, 6],[4,5,6],[6,7], [6], [1]]
```

I want to delete the short lists if the items are included in a long one, even the items are not continuous. So, I expect the result to be:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],[6,7]]
```

I might figure out this by myself, but my way is not smart enough. Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Are the elements in each list unique?

Comment: Why not post your way and ask for help with specific concerns that you have with it? Do you feel your way is inelegant, or slow, or unreliable, or something else?

Comment: @Joonyoung Park yeah, the elements are unique

Comment: @sabik, plz do not think i am too lazy to do this by myself. My idea is like a nested for loops, compare them with each other, make a label for the short lists that need to be deleted. I did not post it here just because I kind of assume this is not good way and it cannot help.

Comment: What's not good about it? Do you think it's inelegant, or slow, or unreliable, or something else?

Comment: @FengChen even if it is not the best way, it will still show how you approached the problem, exactly what you expect and will allow someone to tell you how to fix it and perhaps what a better way is - it's the best way to ask a StackOverflow question, otherwise you are kind of asking people here to write the code for you

Comment: thanks for all your advice. will upload my code later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all the elements in a list is unique, AND I like using sets
here's my code. Haven't checked it's efficiency but it looks cleaner :D

```
t = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 5], [4, 5, 6],[4,5,6],[6,7], [6], [1]]

t = [set(l) for l in t]
t = [list(x) for x in t if not any([x.issubset(y) for y in t if x != y])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort from small to large, make them sets then pop them off the list to reduce the list size for every computation.

```
t=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 5], [4, 5, 6],[4,5,6],[6,7], [6], [1]]

t = sorted(t, key=lambda x: len(x))
t = [set(x) for x in t]
for i in range(len(t)):
    a = t.pop(0)
    if not any([a.issubset(x) for x in t]):
        print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach is very simple

1. I check the last element is already present in our longer list. If we present then we don't need to add to the longer list if it is not the case then we will add to the longerlists

```
sorted_lists=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 5], [4, 5, 6],[4,5,6],[6,7], [6], [1]]

sorted_big_lists =[]
for sorted_list in sorted_lists:
    for test_list in sorted_big_lists:
        if sorted_list[-1] in test_list:
            break
    else:
        sorted_big_lists.append(sorted_list)
  
print(sorted_big_lists)
```